# How to add margin to App.jsx when a child component has 'absolute top-0' styling?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In App.jsx, I have a TopBar component that I want to be shown on every page. I have 'mt-16' in the inline styling.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App w-screen bg-white overflow-x-hidden font-Commissioner">
      <TopBar />
      <Router>        
        <Navbar />
        <div className="ml-12 mt-16">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
            {/* App Routes */}
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
```

It is currently being displayed at the top of every page, but many of my components have an  tag with 'absolute top-0' styling which seems to not do anything from 'mt-16'.

An example is one of my components Landing.jsx:

```
return (
    <section id="Landing">
      <div className="p-4 pt-20 commissioner-font bg-transparent">
        <h1 className="text-3xl text-black-900 h-14 flex flex-col rounded-3xl bg-transparent absolute top-0 left-15">
          <span>Navigation Console</span>
          <span className="text-lg text-gray-500">Manage all your resources and data.</span>
        </h1>
```

When I am on the landing page, the  tag and TopBar overlap.

The only thing I have found is changing each separate component to have 'top-16' from 'top-0', but I wish to have a way to not change every component.

I tried changing every component to have 'top-16' instead of 'top-0' which works, but I really wish there was a better way that doesn't involve changing every file.

Comment: Absolute should be used rarely because it breaks the layout algorithm. It ignores margin for example